# Windows.UI.Xaml.UiElement.IsVisibleChanged doesn't exist

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[`Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) as opposed to [`System.Windows.UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have this event:

[`public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler IsVisibleChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

So two questions:

1. What is the rationale behind not including it?
2. How can it be replaced?

(In code-behind (.xaml.cs), for every `IsVisibleChanged` event or for every `Canvas` resize event I need to rearrange `Canvas`' children.)

Comment: Call `RegisterPropertyChangedCallback` for the `VisibilityProperty`.

Comment: @Clemens yes, that works, thanks; if you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `RegisterPropertyChangedCallback` to register a change callback for the `Visibility` property:

```
element.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, VisibilityChanged);
...

private void VisibilityChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty property)
{
    var visibility = ((UIElement)sender).Visibility;
    ...
}
```